# Delete all messages that aren't by certain author in a discord channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I just finished making a `purge` command that uses a cog to constantly delete messages in a channel when enabled, and not when it is disabled (toggle command). I now want to add one more thing too it, which is it to only purge the messages that aren't by me.

I know this can be done with a simple if statement, but I can't find out what from the discord.py API I need to use. I have been trying to use `message.author.id != "id"`, and other variations of that, but it doesn't seem to work. I am doing this all in my cogs.py and by the way. I have looked at other stack overflow articles about using a log thing from the API and examples of deleting messages with certain keywords in them, but none of them demonstrate exactly the use of the `message.author` stuff and if it's a string or integer, or in fact if I should be using something else.

Here's my code for the bot right now with any attempts at my goal:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    try:
        if self.channels[message.channel]:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=999)
    except:
        pass
```

I have tried stuff like this:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    try:
        if message.author != 396025519398977548 and self[message.channel]:
            await message.delete(message.channel)
    except:
        pass
```

But I am missing something, haha. Still a bit new to python, but I might as well learn along the way by watching from examples and such. This way of learning is easy, but obviously I am getting a book on python to read.

But I digress, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the author name or id. What you got wrong is that message.author.id is an integer and not a string.

- With the author's name :

For instance, if your discord tag is Yolo#5236, you'll have to check `message.author` == 'Yolo'

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    try:
        if self.channels[message.channel] and message.author == 'Your discord name':
            await message.delete()
    except:
        pass
```

- With the author's ID

For instance, if your ID is 48864468684, you'll have to check `message.author.id` == 48864468684

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    try:
        if self.channels[message.channel] and message.author.id == id:
            await message.delete()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: I actually changed it to an integer after this post but I don't remember if I tried it haha. Would know something from the API to delete a user's messages instead of purging all messages from all users? I could only find like fetch users from the docs.

Comment: `message.delete()` will delete the message.